# I can use CyberDuck to connect to S3 Bucket, but I cannot programmatically connect

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to connect to an S3 bucket (A 3rd party is the owner, so I cannot access through AWS console). Using CyberDuck, I can connect and upload files no problem. However I have tried several libraries to connect to the bucket all of which return a 403 forbidden. I am posting here in hopes that someone can spot what I am doing incorrectly.

```
    def send_to_s3(file_name):
        csv = open("/tmp/" + file_name, 'rb')
        conn = tinys3.Connection("SECRET",
                                 "SECRET",
                                 tls=True,
                                 endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com")
        conn.upload("MDA-Data-Ingest/input/" + file_name, csv, bucket="gsext-69qlakrroehhgr0f47bhffnwct")


    def send_via_ftp(file_name):
        cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        cnopts.hostkeys = None
        srv = pysftp.Connection(host="gsext-69qlakrroehhgr0f47bhffnwct.s3.amazonaws.com",
                                username="SECRET",
                                password="SECRET",
                                port=443,
                                cnopts=cnopts)

        with srv.cd('\MDA-Data-Ingest\input'):
            srv.put('\\tmp\\'+file_name)

        # Closes the connection
        srv.close()

    def send_via_boto(file_name):
        access_key = 'SECRET'
        secret_key = 'SECRET'

        conn = boto.connect_s3(
            aws_access_key_id=access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
            host='s3.amazonaws.com',
            # is_secure=False,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
            calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )
```

All of these functions return a 403 forbidden as shown bellow:

HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://gsext-69qlakrroehhgr0f47bhffnwct.s3.amazonaws.com/MDA-Data-Ingest/input/accounts.csv

However when I use CyberDuck I can connect just fine:

[image]

Comment: Edit: At one point the send via ftp was showing the 403 (I cant remember what it looked like when it was sending a 403) as it sits above the error it spits out is:

SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which uses boto3 to access AWS services.

For example:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name --region us-west-2

aws s3 cp s3://gsext-69qlakrroehhgr0f47bhffnwct/MDA-Data-Ingest/input/accounts.csv accounts.csv
```

You would first run `aws configure` to provide your credentials and a default region, but the syntax above allows you to specify the particular region that the bucket is located. (It is possible that your Python code failed due to calling the wrong region.)

Comment: With an almost identical line of code, I was able to get it to work by changing from boto to boto3.